# Half screen is displaying for Android rendering app if system eneter display off state and launch other activity

Tags: android, window, rendering, surface

I need your help on below query on Projection rendering. Please help me.

We have Android rendering HU app. It's properly working in display awake scenario. But, failing in following scenario only.

The use case is

1. Android rendering app(AA) screen is in focus
2. Set Head Unit(HU) to idle mode(Here, AA activity is going to onStop() method)
3. Launch any other app activity in idle mode and destroy it
4. Once other app activity destroyed, AA activity is restarting and going to onResume, OnPause and OnStop.
5. Set HU to display awake
6. The AA screen is displaying half screen size and touch events are working properly as expected in normal case.
7. Please note that if we launch any other activity and came back to AAActivity, then full screen is displaying properly.

Event I tried multiple ways to set scaling factor and margins to SurfaceView, those are NOT reflecting.

I can see the SurfaceView is creating duplicate layer in the logs, but, unable to fix the issue.

It looks like rendering is NOT applying whenever AAActivity is launched. We used OpenGL for rendering. Please help how to fix this issue. Thanks

```
07-07 16:14:26.289  3058  3123 E SurfaceFlinger: SurfaceFlinger. createSurface : SurfaceView - com.xx.xx.androidauto/com.xx.xx.androidauto.application.activity.AAActivity
07-07 16:14:26.290  3058  3058 E SurfaceFlinger: SurfaceFlinger. createLayer : SurfaceView - com.xx.xx.androidauto/com.xx.xx.androidauto.application.activity.AAActivity
07-07 16:14:26.290  3058  3058 D SurfaceFlinger: duplicate layer name: changing SurfaceView - com.xx.xx.androidauto/com.xx.xx.androidauto.application.activity.AAActivity to SurfaceView - com.xx.xx.androidauto/com.xx.xx.androidauto.application.activity.AAActivity#1
07-07 16:14:26.290  3058  3058 E SurfaceFlinger: SurfaceFlinger. getUniqueLayerName returned : SurfaceView - com.xx.xx.androidauto/com.xx.xx.androidauto.application.activity.AAActivity#1
07-07 16:14:26.290  3058  3058 E SurfaceFlinger: SurfaceFlinger. createNormalLayer: SurfaceView - com.xx.xx.androidauto/com.xx.xx.androidauto.application.activity.AAActivity#1
07-07 16:14:26.290  3058  3058 E Layer   : SurfaceFlinger. Creating Layer SurfaceView - com.xx.xx.androidauto/com.xx.xx.androidauto.application.activity.AAActivity#1
07-07 16:14:26.290  3058  3058 E Layer   : SurfaceFlinger. Creating Layer SurfaceView - com.xx.xx.androidauto/com.xx.xx.androidauto.application.activity.AAActivity#1.. Done
07-07 16:14:26.290  3058  3058 E Layer   : SurfaceFlinger. Layer onFirstRef: SurfaceView - com.xx.xx.androidauto/com.xx.xx.androidauto.application.activity.AAActivity#1
07-07 16:14:26.290  3058  3058 E SurfaceFlinger: SurfaceFlinger. setContentsChangedListener
07-07 16:14:26.291  3058  3123 E SurfaceFlinger: SurfaceFlinger. createSurface : Background for - SurfaceView - com.xx.xx.androidauto/com.xx.xx.androidauto.application.activity.AAActivity
07-07 16:14:26.291  3058  3058 E SurfaceFlinger: SurfaceFlinger. createLayer : Background for - SurfaceView - com.xx.xx.androidauto/com.xx.xx.androidauto.application.activity.AAActivity
07-07 16:14:26.291  3058  3058 D SurfaceFlinger: duplicate layer name: changing Background for - SurfaceView - com.xx.xx.androidauto/com.xx.xx.androidauto.application.activity.AAActivity to Background for - SurfaceView - com.xx.xx.androidauto/com.xx.xx.androidauto.application.activity.AAActivity#1
07-07 16:14:26.291  3058  3058 E SurfaceFlinger: SurfaceFlinger. getUniqueLayerName returned : Background for - SurfaceView - com.xx.xx.androidauto/com.xx.xx.androidauto.application.activity.AAActivity#1
07-07 16:14:26.291  3058  3058 E SurfaceFlinger: SurfaceFlinger. createDimLayer: Background for - SurfaceView - com.xx.xx.androidauto/com.xx.xx.androidauto.application.activity.AAActivity#1
07-07 16:14:26.291  3058  3058 E Layer   : SurfaceFlinger. Creating Layer Background for - SurfaceView - com.xx.xx.androidauto/com.xx.xx.androidauto.application.activity.AAActivity#1
07-07 16:14:26.292  3058  3058 E Layer   : SurfaceFlinger. Creating Layer Background for - SurfaceView - com.xx.xx.androidauto/com.xx.xx.androidauto.application.activity.AAActivity#1.. Done
07-07 16:14:26.292  3058  3058 E Layer   : SurfaceFlinger. Layer onFirstRef: Background for - SurfaceView - com.xx.xx.androidauto/com.xx.xx.androidauto.application.activity.AAActivity#1
07-07 16:14:26.292  3058  3058 E SurfaceFlinger: SurfaceFlinger. setContentsChangedListener
07-07 16:14:26.292  3058  3126 E SurfaceFlinger: SurfaceFlinger. setTransactionState

07-07 16:14:26.293  6131  6131 D AapManager: a__surfaceCreated
07-07 16:14:26.293  6131  6131 D AapManager: a__surfaceChanged, layout changed 1724618
07-07 16:14:26.293  6131  6131 D AapManager: AAManager__Setting up the surface
07-07 16:14:26.293  6131  6131 D AapManager: c__inside setSurface
07-07 16:14:26.293  6131  6131 D AapManager: c__mCodec Null
07-07 16:14:26.293  6131  6131 I AapManager: c__codecShouldBeRunning true
07-07 16:14:26.293  6131  6131 D AapManager: c__Surface Rect(0, 0 - 1724, 618) becomes Rect(0, 0 - 1724, 618) for video Rect(0, 0 - 1724, 618)
```

dumpsys window windows contains snapshot for AAActivity.

```
  SnapshotCache
    Entry taskId=23
      topApp=AppWindowToken{301d136 token=Token{e9cf912 ActivityRecord{30b709d u0 com.xx.xx.androidauto/.application.activity.AAActivity t23}}}
      snapshot=TaskSnapshot{mSnapshot=android.graphics.GraphicBuffer@c2f421c mOrientation=2 mContentInsets=[196,102][0,0] mReducedResolution=false mScale=1.0
```

I tried multiple ways to apply rendering and ried to stop display focus in idle mode, still no luck.